# D3.js with Python, rendering a blank page

Tags: python-3.x, d3.js

Setup: I'm trying to create a simple D3 js demo with Python 3 handling requests. Following the steps below I expected to see an error or some kind of HTML generated when I click on my html page with my d3 method. Instead, I receive a blank page.

## 1) Create custom HTTPRequestHandler class to handle GET requests

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import os

class HTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    #handle GET command
    def do_GET(self):
        rootdir = r'C:\Current_Working_Directory' #file location
        try:
            if self.path.endswith('.json'):
                f = open(rootdir + self.path, 'rb') #open requested file

                #send code 200 response
                self.send_response(200)

                #send header first
                self.send_header('Content-type','applicaon/json')
                self.end_headers()

                #send file content to client
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
                return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404, 'file not found')

def run():
    print('http server is starting...')

    #ip and port of server
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 80)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, HTTPRequestHandler)
    print('http server is running...')
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

## 2) Save above file as server.py and run python server.py and create some dummy json data stored in data.json in $rootdir and create d3.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>D3 tutorial 10</title>
    <script src=”http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js”></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    d3.json(“dummy.json”, function (error,data) {
        if (error) return console.warn(error);
        console.log(data)

    });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

## 4) Open up web page expecting to see an error or some indication that d3 has sent the GET request to the server, but get a blank page.

Comment: Did you inspect the network traffic browser <-> server?

Comment: Your nesting appears to be off in your code above for 1).  The function do_GET should be nested one more level, as it is part of the class.  I've edited it as so, so please correct if necessary.

Comment: @aventurin I tried 3 different browsers and various security configs

Comment: @Anony with network traffic I mean the HTTP requests and responses. The info you get if you e.g. hit F12 in Chrome.

Comment: @aventurin Oh, I got an error complaining about Access-Control-Allow-Origin so I added the proper header in the server. Now, the problem seems to be the HTTP GET request is going through, but not returning any data to javascript (it says null when I try to log it to the console).

Comment: If you connect with your browser to a web server, you should always get a HTTP response that's visible in the browser's network console (either success, or failure). In the rare cases when this is not the case the error log of your web server should give you a hint what's going wrong.